# Anti matter of gravity

Tags: gravity, quantum-gravity, antimatter

We all know that the fundamental particles to be controlling the electric and magnetic forces in our universe are obtained in pairs(electrons and protons, north pole and south pole.) Likewise I guess it is safe to assume that even the weakest long range force,Gravity, also follows the same. So, is anti-gravity real or just a rubbish idea of my tiny brain?Also I think this might be related to the Quantum realms.

Comment: >"Likewise I guess it is safe to assume that even the weakest long range force,Gravity, also follows the same."  No, it is not a safe assumption. The two kinds of charges  *does NOT imply that gravity must have two kinds of masses.*   Masses always act attractively and if you read the duplicates you will see that only limits can be given for any kind of repulsive gravity.

Comment: North Pole and South Pole in gravity do exist and refer to gravitomagnetism: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitoelectromagnetism - but it is not anti-gravity. In electromagnetism, like charges repulse. In gravity, it is the opposite, like "charges" (masses) attract. For a repulsion you need a negative mass, something that makes time go faster. Nothing like this has been found so far.

Answer (score 1):

The particle that conveys the electromagnetic particle is the photon, not the electron or positron. The force between them is carried by photons; the photons themselves are not subject to the electromagnetic force.

The (hypothetical) [graviton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graviton) is a boson like the photon. And like the photon, the graviton is its own anti-particle. So there are no anti-gravity particles ;-(

Comment: "particle that conveys the electromagnetic particle" - what does this mean? "The force between them is carried by photons" - No, the force carriers are *virtual* photons, but virtual particles don't exist, so photons don't carry a force. "photons themselves are not subject to the electromagnetic force" - example, the Compton scattering is mediated by a virtual electron interacting with a photon and making it scatter. "graviton is a boson like the photon" - then how does it curve spacetime? "there are no anti-gravity" - then why is "dark energy" repulsive? You just repeat "official" mantras.